# How do we know the Gamma function Γ(n-1)?

Tags: proof-explanation, special-functions, gamma-function

We know that $\Gamma(n)=(n−1)!$ and I do not know how $\Gamma(n-1)$ equal to?
Is there a proof for that.
I tried and got $\Gamma(n-1)= n\Gamma(n)$ but I'm not sure is correct or not

Is there any proof or formal that will help??

Comment: Use the standard integral representation $\Gamma(n)=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ and integrate by parts to find $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)\Gamma(n-1)$.

Comment: @Clayton The OP does not have the correct functional relationship.

Comment: You mean $\Gamma(n+1)=n\Gamma(n)$ don't you?

Comment: @saulspatz I already commented on this.

Comment: @Yes, I know you did, but I thought I'd call the OP's attention to it a bit more explicitly.

Comment: Another way is to start with $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st} dt=\frac{1}{s}$ for $s>0$ and differentiate with respect to $s$, multiple times.

Comment: If you know $\Gamma(n)=(n−1)!$ remplace $n$ by $(n-1)$ and you got  $\Gamma(n-1)=((n-1)−1)!=(n-2)!$.

Comment: @Mark: whoops, I read $n+1$ instead of $n-1$.